# Load symbols in release build in Visual Studio Performance Profiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler

I have a C++ project that builds a lib and a test executable that calls that lib in Visual studio 2019 community edition. Now I would like to profile the lib to see where the bottlenecks are. When I use the Performance Profiler in debug mode, it shows exactly which functions are being called and where in de code this  but when I use Release mode, all I see are hex adresses of functions like "Test.exe!0x0000013f216503". I guess the profiler cannot find the .pdb files.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Change your visual studio configuration to generate pdb files on Release mode too.

Comment: Indeed, using Project Properties -> Linker -> Debugging and setting "Generate Debug Info" to "/DEBUG" shows me function names. However, I still get a message "source information is not available" if I click on the function. Do you also know how to turn this on?

Comment: Normally the source information is embedded in the PDB file, and on the same machine it should automatically find the source. If not you need to set the profiler's source path somehow. Does it find the source if you just debug?

Comment: Yes it does show it in Debug mode.

Comment: It appears that only the source code of the static lib is missing. The test executable code is shown.

Comment: Did you build the lib with debug information as well, then? Common mistake to make.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Setting Project properties -> C/C++ -> General, and then "Debug Information format" to "Program database" makes it work as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Also disabling optimizations for speed seems to impact the output. Some functions that were missing are shown when optimizations are disabled

Comment: Some functions were missing? Do you mean they were inlined?